# Redis Background Rewrite AOF completed with error

Tags: redis, persistence, redis-server

I've redis deployed on windows server 2016.

`appendonly.aof` file volume is getting bigger, taking all disk free space.

I tried to do a BGREWRITEAOF to reduce it, but it terminated with error.

```
[6268] 12 Sep 09:19:10.710 * Background AOF rewrite terminated with success
[6268] 12 Sep 09:19:10.711 * Residual parent diff successfully flushed to the rewritten AOF (0.00 MB)
[6268] 12 Sep 09:19:11.250 # Error trying to rename the temporary AOF file temp-rewriteaof-bg-6268.aof into appendonly.aof: Input/output error
```

Additional Inforomations:

```
Redis server v=3.2.100
```

Persistence:

```
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:0
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1694506742
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can may be solved by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75109663/aof-file-becomes-empty-when-i-perform-bgrewriteaof-in-redis).
Unfortunately, I found these questions are similar, but they couldn't find a solution as well:

[How to limit size of appendonly.aof redis file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70783375/how-to-limit-size-of-appendonly-aof-redis-file)

https://serverfault.com/questions/825883/redis-appendonly-aof-file-size-out-of-control